# Google app engine Storage

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I created an application that displays emergency numbers and allows the user to add their own emergency numbers to the list.

I also created a web application project to handle the server part of the app.

I can run it locally, but I need to store it globally on the GAE.

I am aware that I need an application ID, but how do I link my android application to that web application that I have deployed?

Do I need to insert the API key somewhere and switch on any services?

Its not creating my numbers now if I deploy so I know Im doing it wrong. Please please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [Api Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) you need to enable the "Google Cloud Messaging For Android" service.

Then, In "API Access" tab, you need to add a **Server Key**, and an **Android Key** (actually two android keys - one for debug and one later for the released version - don't forget that!)

Then in the Endpoint classes you need to add the following to the @Api annotation:
**clientIds** - The Ids of the Android Client Keys
**audiences** - The "Client ID for web applications"

Which will eventually look like this:

```
@Api(name = "endpoint_name"
    clientIds = {"porject_number-android_debug_key.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                 "porject_number-android_release_key.apps.googleusercontent.com"},
    audiences = {"project_number.apps.googleusercontent.com"})
```

Above the class declaration.